# Not Populating all option in ListBoxFor using Chosen Select plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

in html select tag showing all options but down side of this select tag one div is there with class Chosen-drop, there all item is not showing

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.GetAllBlockList, Model.GetBlockList, new { @class = "form-control chosenselect", @tabindex = "2", @id = "BlockId" })
```

on Browser it is showing like below html code

```
  <div class="sim-col-3 col-md-3">
 <select class="form-control chosenselect" id="BlockId" multiple="multiple" name="GetAllBlockList" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><option value="1">Utility - Ph I</option>
<option value="2">Block 12</option>
<option value="3">STP I</option>
<option value="4">Block 10</option>
<option value="5">Block 5</option>
<option value="6">Block 6</option>
<option value="7">Block 7</option>
<option value="8">Block 8</option>
<option value="9">Block 9</option>
<option value="10">Block 11</option>
<option value="11">MLCP</option>
<option value="12">Block 2</option>
<option value="13">Block 14</option>
<option value="14">Food Court</option>
<option value="15">Block 2</option>
<option value="16">Block 3</option>
<option value="17">Food Court</option>
<option value="18">Block 1</option>
<option value="19">Block 4</option>
<option value="20">Block 15</option>
<option value="21">Block 4</option>
<option value="22">Surya Park I</option>
<option value="23">Surya Park II</option>
<option value="24">Surya Sapphire</option>
<option value="25">Surya Wave</option>
<option value="26">test block</option>
<option value="27">55555</option>
</select><div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active" style="width: 240px;" title="" id="BlockId_chosen">
    <ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Select Some Options" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 147px;" tabindex="2">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <ul class="chosen-results">
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0" style="">Utility - Ph I</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">Block 12</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">STP I</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3" style="">Block 10</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4" style="">Block 5</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5" style="">Block 6</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="6" style="">Block 7</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="7" style="">Block 8</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="8" style="">Block 9</li>
            <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="9" style="">Block 11</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="10" style="">MLCP</li></ul></div></div>
                </div>
```

So in Chosen Drop its showing only 10 items

Comment: Unfortunately this question is extremely low quality, please spend a small amount of time to show us the markup or code, and be a little more specific about the problem, whats happening and what you expect

Comment: actually i am beginner , i am very sorry to not to be specific , my problem is i am trying to bind multiple select dropdown on change of some other dropdown . fortunately its working but not showing all the items its showing maximum 10 items

Comment: can u please check once now? i have edited

Comment: This is a big improvement, hopefully someone can help you out

Comment: @GunjanJha What is the question here? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: only 10 item is showing in dropdown . but if we see under <select> almost 30 item is there@RahulSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason behind this.

there will be one Chosen.Jquery.js file. there we need to update the code like this.max_shown_results="The Number we want"